# Can I use a Mac Mini with a HDMI switch?

Tags: mac-mini, screen, hdmi, power

I’ve been trying to use a HDMI switch to use both my work computer and personal computer (Mac Mini 2011) on the same screen.

However when I have both laptops and the switch plugged into the screen, I cannot power on the Mac Mini.

Only when the Mac Mini is plugged directly to the screen does it power on.

The screen is a Benq GL2460.

I found [this discussion page](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251705916) but it doesn’t have a solution.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why an HDMI cable would prevent the Mini from powering on. What year model of Mini is it? Have you tried connecting a USB-C to HDMI adaptor to one of the TB ports instead?

Comment: I edited my question. There is an HDMI and a Thunderbolt to HDMI plugged in the mac mini but it will only power on if the HDMI is plugged to the screen directly. Won’t turn on in the thunderbolt to HDMI is plugged to the projector and the projector is off for example